# How to create Rewrite rule to redirect POST request from two addresses to "http://localhost/anpr/" in Microsoft IIS 10?

Tags: post, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I would like to redirect two POST request form Dahua ANPR camera to one script in Microsoft IIS. I would like to redirect POST request from "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/KeepAlive" and "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo" to "http://localhost/anpr/". I have created rules in the main configuration file "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config":

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
        <match url="(.*)/NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/anpr/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="NotificationInfo/KeepAlive">
        <match url="(.*)/NotificationInfo/KeepAlive$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/anpr/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo/" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
        <match url="(.*)/NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo/" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/anpr/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="NotificationInfo/KeepAlive/">
        <match url="(.*)/NotificationInfo/KeepAlive/$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/anpr/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

IIS 10 returns error "HTTP 404.0 — Not Found" for "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/KeepAlive" and "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo". Address "http://localhost/anpr/" works. "anpr" is a folder with a script "index.php". What did I do wrong? How to do such redirection? How to do Rewrite rule to redirect from "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/KeepAlive" and "http://localhost/NotificationInfo/TollgateInfo" to "http://localhost/anpr/"? Could you help me?

Comment: Typical mistake 1, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your url, you can try the following rule:

```
  <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^NotificationInfo/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/anpr" />
  </rule>
```

[image]